# not able to install Caldav gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, caldav

I want to access a Darwin iCal server which i have implemented using my Rails application. I would like to create events and access the server to get events in specific date range. When I tried to install the [Caldav gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/caldav), I am getting a dependency with the "rexml" gem.

> Could not find gem 'rexml (>= 0) ruby', which is required by gem
>   'caldav (>= 0) ruby', in any of the sources.

Unfortunately rexml is not there in gemscutter or any other sources. Any idea how I can use the Caldav gem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try this https://rubygems.org/gems/twisted-caldav

basically we modified some other caldav client and customised for out needs... 
but it works with ubuntu calenderserver

Answer (score 1):

try this in your Gemfile

```
gem 'ruby-caldav', github: 'martinpovolny/ruby-caldav'
```

If it does not work try this Caldav fork gem instead:

https://github.com/agilastic/agcaldav

Comment: Nope. getting this error

Could not find gem 'ruby-caldav (>= 0) ruby' in
git://github.com/martinpovolny/ruby-caldav.git (at master).
Source does not contain any versions of 'ruby-caldav (>= 0) ruby'